# Call vue js function with php parameters in blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I am using vue js cdn in my laravel project.
I would like to call a vue js function within blade, but there seems to be an error somewhere (the page loads blank)

```
<table >
  <head>
   <th>Order ID</th>
   <th>Aging</th>
  </head>
  @foreach($orders as $order) 
   <tr>
     <td>{{ $order->OrderID }}</td>  
     <td>@{{ relativeDate({{ $order }}) }}</td>                                       
    </tr>
  @endforeach    
</table>
```

However, when I call the function inside a click event, it works

```
<button @click="relativeDate({{ $order }})">>Button</button>
```

Comment: Check your Laravel logs in `storage/logs` to see if any errors are showing there

Comment: There is no error related to my issue in the log file

Comment: try checking your console on your browser dev-tools

Comment: @KevinYobeth no error appears on the console

Answer (score 1):

$order is object and its php, so you have render to js json with `relativeDate(<?=json_encode($order)?>)`

or render loop via js

insert your  $orders be a data on vue component
and loop via v-for

Answer (score 0):

mybe you must to show your logic js vue used to handle, i things have error on there.

Comment: the error is not on the method side since it works perfectly with the click event

Comment: Why dont you loop the button inside the TD element. Is it possible to put a function like that in a TD element ? ( I am still learning Laravel and code basically)